# how to solve the Your manifest description is missing., Missing Name, issue Unable to generate PWA package, issue with Manifest?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have two similar environments: one for development (Dev) and one for User Acceptance Testing (UAT). In both environments, I have an Angular web application hosted in an S3 bucket, and the corresponding API is deployed on Elastic Beanstalk. I have attempted to generate the Progressive Web App (PWA) package for both environments using the same build that was deployed to each.

Interestingly, I was able to successfully generate the PWA package from the Dev environment. However, when attempting to generate the package from the UAT environment, the PWA builder is unable to identify the manifest file.

I find it perplexing that this issue has occurred, as both environments are identical and the builds deployed to them are derived from a single build. I am unsure of the reason behind this discrepancy.

If you have any insights or suggestions as to why this might be happening, your input would be greatly appreciated.

i tried by uploading the dev manifest into uat environment still it is not working.
if i upload the uat environment manifest file to dev , it works fine in dev environment